# Incrementing an int inside if boolean expression

Tags: java

I would like to understand how can the int x be incremented inside an if (Boolean expression) for every loop iteration
How is that possible?? How does it work?

```
  public class MethodsTest {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x= 0;

    for (int z = 0; z < 5; z++) 
    {

        if(x++ > 2){

        }

        System.out.println(x);
    }

}
 }
```

the output will be
 
1
2
3
4
5

Comment: Look up post-increment operator in Java.

Comment: `x++` means "Save the current value of x, increment x and store it back where it came from, then 'return' the saved value to be used in the enclosing expression."

Comment: (And note that `++x` is similar, only the incremented value is "returned" to be used in the enclosing expression.)

Comment: So it is legal to change variables inside the boolean part of an if statement? ?

Comment: It is absolutely `legal` to do this.

Comment: It's "legal".  Not always advisable, but legal.  (But, in particular, the use of the `x++` idiom in such cases is so firmly established that it's useless to lobby against it,.)

Answer (score 8):

`x++` is a compound assignment operator, which is equivalent to `x = x + 1`, with the side effect taking place *after* the evaluation. Therefore, the `if` statement is equivalent to a pair of statements like this:

```
    if(x > 2) {
        x = x + 1;
        // At this point, the side effect has taken place, so x is greater than it was before the "if"
        ...
    } else {
        // The side effect takes place regardless of the condition, hence the "else"
        x = x + 1;
    }
```

Note that this code is forced to repeat the `x = x + 1` part. Using `++` lets you avoid this repetition.

There is a pre-increment counterpart of `x++` - namely, `++x`. In this form the assignment takes place *before* the expression is evaluated, so the condition becomes

```
if ((x = x + 1) > 2) {
    // Note that the condition above uses an assignment. An assignment is also an expression, with the result equal to
    // the value assigned to the variable. Like all expressions, it can participate in a condition.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To break your notion that the condition of an `if` can't "do things", imagine that you have a function that returns a boolean, like:

```
boolean areThereCookies(int numCookies)
{
    return numCookies > 0;
}
```

then you could use it in your `if` statement:

```
if (areThereCookies(cookies))
{
    eatCookies(cookies);
}
```

However the method `areThereCookies(int)` that we are calling to evaluate the `if` condition could be making anything in the world. It could change variable values, read input, write output, steal cookies...

So the language is perfectly capable of "doing things" in the if evaluation. The other answers explain what your code was specifically doing.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to have expressions inside a if statement as long as the expression resolves to a boolean. For example,

```
int i = 0
if (i = i + 1)
```

is not a valid expression inside an if statement because the expressions resolves to 1, which is an integer.
    However,

```
int i = 0
if (2 == i = 2)
```

is a valid expression because 2 is first assigned to the variable i and then is compared to 2, and thus the expression resolves to “true”.
    In your example if statement, you have a post-incremented variable x that is compared against 2 with the greater than operator, resulting in a boolean value, and thus it is a valid expression. Hotlinks has described what a post-incremented variable is in the comments.